# suggest simplest way to compare strange fraction.

Tags: fractions, partial-fractions, percentages

I am doing certain data-interpretation questions. In data-interpretation I am consistently encountering the percentage calculation. sometimes calculations are simple but most of the time they are time consuming mentally like inscribed below

$$ \frac{{\rm 84}}{{\rm 112}}\times 100\%  =75\%$$
$$ \frac{{\rm 84}}{{\rm 107}}\times 100\%  =78.5\%$$
$$ \frac{{\rm 63}}{{\rm 80}}\times 100\%  =78.75\%$$
$$ \frac{{\rm 104}}{{\rm 131}}\times 100\%  =79.39\%$$

In the above calculations , the percentage calculations takes too much time to calculate & come up with results mentally .

consider above two calculations or fractions which are

$$ \frac{{\rm 84}}{{\rm 112}}\times 100\%  $$ 
$$ \&\& $$

$$ \frac{{\rm 84}}{{\rm 107}}\times 100\%  $$

in this case we can immediately will says the $$ \frac{{\rm 84}}{{\rm 107}}\times 100\% $$ is maximum because of the denominator comparison.

but how to predict in the following cases or rest of the cases
$$ \frac{{\rm 84}}{{\rm 107}}\times 100\% $$
$$ \frac{{\rm 63}}{{\rm 80}}\times 100\%  $$
$$ \frac{{\rm 104}}{{\rm 131}}\times 100\% $$

how to say which is maximum or minimum.mentally without calculator?

Any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: don't know any simple rules unfortunately. You may want to look into the Trachtenberg system for quickly doing complex arithmetic problems in your mind.

Comment: For $\dfrac{84}{107}$ and $\dfrac{63}{80}$, you can use that $84=4\cdot21$ and $63=3\cdot21$.  

For $\dfrac{63}{80}$ and $\dfrac{104}{131}$, you can use that $\dfrac{63}{80}=\dfrac{64}{80}\dfrac{63}{64}=\dfrac{4}{5}\dfrac{63}{64}$, whereas $\dfrac{104}{131}=\dfrac{8\cdot13}{10\cdot13}\dfrac{130}{131}=\dfrac{4}{5}\dfrac{130}{131}$.